# Where does ${x.y.z} get defined for the properties file?

Tags: java, maven, configuration, properties-file

In the project we have many .properties files. Typically they have entries such as

`app.sandox.folder=/path/folder`

but in other .properties files they have entries such as

`app.sandbox.folder=${app.sandbox.folder}`

I cannot figure out where *${app.sandbox.folder}* is set. Can anyone clarify for me what this is and where or what file the item is declared or how it works?

Comment: Yes the project is using Maven. No I don't know Maven. Well I know how to spell it :)

Comment: Well, then one place is `profiles` in your `pom.xml`, look for something like `<app.sandbox.folder>something <app.sandbox.folder/>`

Comment: @ReservoirSampling I see it and it specifies another external properties file which contains the values. Huge help thank you!

Comment: no issues, happy to help :)

Comment: @ReservoirSampling if you put your response in as an Answer I can flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Maven, one place to check for these properties is `profiles` in your `pom.xml`.

Check for something like

```
<app.sandbox.folder> value <app.sandbox.folder/>
```

or an external properties file which has these properties will be defined in `<configuration>`.